# Erro ao Implantar Label na api google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

Ola pessoal não tenho muito conhecimento de java script e preciso de uma ajuda, de como implantar um codigo na api do google maps para criar um label em cada ponto.
A baixo estou colocando o meu codigo e se alguem poder me ajudar a me informar oque estou fazendo de errado (Os label não aparecem) 
Essa  imagen e como queria que funciona-se
[image: E exatamente isso que eu presiso]

[Peguei esse exemplo aqui](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/docs/examples.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="../gerenciador/assets/components/library/jquery/jquery.min.js?   v=v2.1.0"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="label.js"></script>
```

```
 <style type="text/css">
.labels {
 color: red;
 background-color: white;
 font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 width: 40px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 white-space: nowrap;
 }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cliente/label.js"></script>

<script>
var infoWindow = null;  
var map = null;
var markersArray = [];
function initialize() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-22.904546, -43.097979);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom : 8,
        center : myLatlng,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
      var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
      trafficLayer.setMap(map);
      //  Inicio do Jonson para altera a cor do Mapa
    var pink_parks = [
 ];
 map.setOptions({styles: pink_parks});

 directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();    
 directionsDisplay.setMap(map);        

       // Fim do jonson     

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;                
    updateMaps();
    window.setInterval(updateMaps, 30000);
 }

 function clearOverlays() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
   markersArray[i].setMap(null);
  }
 } 

/*
 * Método que realiza chama o caminho do xml de dados
 * e atualiza o mapa
 */ 
function updateMaps() {

    // Vamos remover o que já havia de overlay
    // É possível implementar a remoção e inclusão seletiva
    clearOverlays();


    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    var data = 'gps/dataxml.xml?t=' + timestamp;

    //Me guardo o direito a não explicar o óbvio, novamente
    $.get(data, {}, function(data) {
        $(data).find("gps").each(

                function() {
                    var gps = $(this);
                    var nome = gps.attr("nome");
                    var alti = gps.attr("alti");
                    var bateria = gps.attr("bateria");
                    var id_saida = gps.attr("id_saida");
                    var id_motorista = gps.attr("id_motorista");
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(gps
                            .attr("lat")), parseFloat(gps.attr("longi")));
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position : latlng,
   map : map,
   title: id_saida,
   //icon: icon.icon,
   labelContent: "$425K",
   labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
   labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
   labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75} ,                           
                    });
                //Opa... bora guardar as referências dos markers??
                markersArray.push(marker);

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function()   
   {});
                });
        });
    0
    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

    </script>
  <body  class="" style="background: #4a8bc2; " onload="hidden()" >
  <div class="">
  <div id="" style="height: 460px;">    
  <div id="map_canvas" style="position: absolute; top: 10%;  left: 0%;      
   width: 100%; height: 765px"></div>
  <div id="log"></div></div>
  </div></p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

meu xml

```
  <gps><gps lat="-23.000787" longi="-43.001940" id_motorista="124" p_nome="Murilo Barros" nome="Fabio H de O Rangel" p_tipo_veiculo="" id_saida="308" start="16/Mar/3" hora_start="" p_tipo_serv="" title="" vei="BUS" placa="kov-6095" cor="" foto1="" fotom="0cf4cf381a80d3c9c94fd0b388cf22ad.jpg" id_pax=""/>
    <gps lat="-23.000787" longi="-43.001940" id_motorista="124" p_nome="Murilo Barros" nome="Fabio H de O Rangel" p_tipo_veiculo="" id_saida="308" start="16/Mar/3" hora_start="" p_tipo_serv="" title="" vei="BUS" placa="kov-6095" cor="" foto1="" fotom="0cf4cf381a80d3c9c94fd0b388cf22ad.jpg" id_pax=""/>
    <gps lat="-22.709931" longi="-42.626153" id_motorista="75" p_nome="Colombia - 16 pax" nome="CARLA RODRIGUES DE VASCONCELLOS" p_tipo_veiculo="" id_saida="305" start="16/Mar/3" hora_start="" p_tipo_serv="" title="" vei="BUS" placa="lpz-4050" cor="" foto1="" fotom="f9db82872944c9af856e9753bef0c7cc.jpg" id_pax=""/>
    <gps lat="-22.909909" longi="-42.626167" id_motorista="81" p_nome="Mariana Wyse" nome="Fabio Guia" p_tipo_veiculo="" id_saida="307" start="16/Mar/3" hora_start="" p_tipo_serv="" title="" vei="BUS" placa="kov-6555" cor="" foto1="" fotom="14db0116f632d1ef5c1b6039ec9e33b9.jpg" id_pax=""/>
  </gps>
```